# People Search Result page

Tags: people-search

.../searchresults/pages/peopleresults.aspx#Default={"k":"domain\username1 OR domain\username2","o":[{"p":"LevelsToTop","d":1},{"p":"LastName","d":0}]}

Is there any way that I can make my search against a specific column, e.g. AccountName in above search query?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution by NOT putting the target column name at front of the very first criteria, shown as bellow e.g. search against AccountName

```
.../searchresults/pages/peopleresults.aspx#Default={"k":"domain\\username1 OR  AccountName=domain\\username2","o":[{"p":"LevelsToTop","d":1},{"p":"LastName","d":0}]}
```